# Are inserts and interjections the same thing?

Tags: interjections

I'm reading Biber's Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English.
At some point the author lists families of words, which are: lexical words, function words and inserts. 
And then, after the unit devoted to function words he describes a 'special classes of words', among them single-word classes, wh-words, numerals and interjection. 
I'm just starting my adventure with studying English grammar thus I'd like to know whether these two notions are one and the same thing.

Comment: I'm guessing that _inserts_ are a strictly broader class than _interjections_. (So all interjections are inserts, but not vice versa.) Just guessing.

Comment: @Keep these mind: [*More recently, **interjections** have been variously identified as adverbs (the catch-all category), pragmatic particles, discourse markers, and single-word clauses. Others have characterized interjections as pragmatic noises, response cries, reaction signals, expressives, **inserts**, and evincives.*](http://grammar.about.com/od/words/a/Oh-Wow-Notes-On-Interjections.htm) The implication of *that* is that "inserts" are a subset of "interjections", not vice-versa.

Comment: ...there's also [*Biber et al. use the cover term **insert** because **interjections** "do not form an integral part of a syntactic structure".*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=srlwCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=linguistics+insert+or+interjection&source=bl&ots=exXSxBGPI5&sig=5gcTC9yKJHH9YfTudxYRLSn68mY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNmpPQx7zPAhUDmh4KHYx2A40Q6AEIRjAG#v=onepage&q=linguistics%20insert%20or%20interjection&f=false)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The first seems, _uhm_, wrong. The second quote, _eh_, supports my guess ("cover term").

Comment: @Keep these mind: It's hardly a cut & dried distinction. I'm not a linguist, but a couple of minutes on Google give me the impression that ***insert*** is really just a new term introduced by "Biber et al" less than 20 years ago. It may not be all that widely recognised (yet, or *ever*).

Comment: The few bits that I found (on Google) seem to suggest that vocative expressions, _FumbleFingers_, are supposedly _inserts_ too. @FumbleFingers I may be wrong.

Comment: Biber et al study gigantic linguistic archives via computer and annotate the actual patterns that occur. Often they find that -- as here -- resort to traditional terminology complicates their description, so they introduce and define their own terminology instead. They have the data; they can do that. Description comes after data, not before.

Comment: @John: I don't recall you referring to *interjections* and/or *inserts* often if ever, but I think I've picked up ***discourse marker*** mainly from you. Do you think of *interjection / insert* as subcategories within *discourse marker*, or are they just not particularly useful classifications?

Comment: I don't really pay attention to those very much, and thus have no particular use for either term, but I would use them differently if I had to. They are not terms in the same system.